# OnClick Event not working on android HTML Viewer

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, onclick

Just looking for some help in relation to the onClick event not working on my android Galaxy S4 html Viewer, It works just fine on my desktop but when I view the files from my galaxy the onclick event doesnt do anything at all.
All help appreciated! 
Thanks!

Div that I want to click touch to trigger the function:

`<div id = "ChangeContentButton1" onclick="displayDifferentContent()">
    </div>`

I want to change the Content of this :

```
    <div id = "content">NO CONTENT YET, PRESS A BUTTON</div>
```

The function I want to call to change the content :

```
function displayDifferentContent(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "DIFFERENT CONTENT";}
```